# Python Converting String to jpg file

Tags: python, python-3.x, jpeg

I have a file with strings that were pulled out of our HR system that are images of people that work for our company.  I wrote the following code to convert these strings into .jpg files.

`d` is the name of the new file and `x` is the image string.  I have printed both of these variables and they seem to be working.  The file is saving and it is 71KB but when I open it in paint it says that it "cannot read this file and This is not a valid bitmap file, or its format is not currently supported."

I opened it with Photos and it just said it "can't open this file." Are you able to see any issue with the code?

```
import csv
import base64
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

with open(file_path, 'r') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    next(readCSV)
    for line in readCSV:
        d = line[0]
        x = line[1]
        y = base64.encodebytes(x.encode())

        with open("C:\\%s.jpg" %(d), "wb") as fh:
            fh.write(base64.decodebytes(y))
            fh.close()
        break
```